# this.set is not a function error

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Inside my controller I have this code to fade out a div:

```
popUpFadeOut: function(){
if(this.get('bid.popUpContainerOpacity') === 0){
this.set('bid.popUpContainerOpacity', 1);
this.set('bid.popUpContainerDisplay', 'block');   
setTimeout(this.fading, 1000); //popup box fades away after 1 seconds
}
},

fading: function() {
    this.set('bid.popUpContainerOpacity', 'bid.popUpContainerOpacity' - 0.1);

    if (this.get('bid.popUpContainerOpacity') <= 0)
    {
       this.set('bid.popUpContainerOpacity', 0);
       this.set('bid.popUpContainerDisplay', 'none');
    }
    else
    { 
       requestAnimationFrame(this.fading);
    }
},
```

Inside the fading function, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.set is not a function(…)
```

While I'm not an expert on the 'this' keyword, my guess is that it cannot find the function because fading gets called inside popUpFadeout, so calling this.set in fading will look for a set method inside popUpFadeOut, which does not exist.

My question is: How do I get access to the set method of my controller inside fading?

Comment: try `setTimeout(this.fading.bind(this), 1000);` instead

Comment: @DiogoSgrillo Now it says Cannot read property 'set' of undefined(…) inside fading.

Comment: I put '.bind(this)' on the other this.fading too and now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your timeout call, shift to `this.fading.bind(this)`. You should then have the proper `this` bound to be used  when calling set